# If A commutes with B, does A commute with the Cholesky decomposition of B?

Tags: matrices, matrix-decomposition

If
$A B=B A$
where $A$ is a square matrix and $B$ a square positive definite matrix.

$B$ has a [Cholesky decomposition](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Cholesky_decomposition)
$$B=L L^*$$

Does $A$ commute with $L$ and $L^*$?

Naturally if $A$ commutes with $L$ and $L^*$, then $A$ commutes with $B$, but it doesn't seem anywhere near as obvious in the other direction.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Unfortunately even $B$ itself does not commute with its own Cholesky decomposition. A concrete counterexample is $$B = \begin{pmatrix} 2 & 1 \\ 1 & 2 \end{pmatrix}$$ which does not commute with $L = \begin{pmatrix} \sqrt{2} & \sqrt{1/2} \\ 0 & \sqrt{3/2} \end{pmatrix}.$ (I am relying on wolframalpha's computation of the Cholesky decomposition here.)